# Derivatives or Integrals of Factorials

Tags: calculus, factorial

I am wondering, why is it so hard to take the derivative or integral of a factorial function defined as $f(x) = x!$.

I know that approximations do exist, and it wouldn't be so hard to subject them to derivation or integration. I doubt that the reason is that factorials are defined only for whole numbers...

Is my thought right? What other things make this kind of a derivation seemingly hard (or impossible) to get ?

One thing I did is like this:
$$ (n+1)! - n! = n\times n!$$

This is a commonly known thing.

Now, derivatives are defined as (I am very much of a noob in calculus, even if I know a little bit of it):
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\dfrac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$
Taking $f(x) = x!$, when we try to take the derivative:
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)! - x!}h$$

In this case, simple substitution won't work, and since I don't know many other rules well, maybe I won't be able to work it out well.

But if I try to use Lagrange's mean value theorem to see if there is a place where the $f(x)$ here has a minima or a maxima (I only have a small knowledge about this) here, I'd have $f'(c) = \dfrac{a! - b!}{a-b}$  ($a$ and $b$ are distinct) and this can't be zero anywhere, since factorials are defined only for positive integers and $a = b$ means that the $f'(c)$ we get enters indeterminate forms.

Anything more that I can go through to understand why $\dfrac d{dx}{x!}$ is hard to evaluate ?

Comment: FYI, check on the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: @JohnOmielan , I have heard of it.. it's an improper integral, right ?

Comment: You need to decide what things like $\pi!$ means. Once you've done that (most conventionally through the gamma function, as mentioned above), the rest is probably doable. I personally wouldn't _call_ it "the factorial function" any more, though.

Comment: An integral defined on (integer) factorial is discrete, while derivatives and integrals demand *continuous* functions.  One *can* take a derivative and integrate a gamma function, however.

Comment: @Arthur , I only meant to know why it' hard to work with calculus tools like integration and differentiation on factorials...

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am wondering, why is it so hard to take the derivative or integral of a factorial function

> I doubt that the reason is that factorials are defined only for whole numbers.

That's *exactly* the reason. Calculus tools are made to handle functions defined on (most of) the real number line. That's their raison d'être. They can't really handle a function that is defined only on the integers, without either a massive reworking of calculus itself, or redefining the function to have a value everywhere.

Comment: Thanks, @Arthur !

Comment: but I still doubt if $\lim_{h \to 1}\dfrac{(x+h)! - x!}{h}$ is capable of being evaluated... is it possible ?

Comment: I know that it can't approach a limit from both sides... but still ?

Comment: @Spectre You can't approach the limit at all. So there is no limit, the expression has no value. Not even close to anything resembling a value. It is thoroughly undefined.

Comment: but why doesn't it approach a limit ? How can I understand it graphically ?

Comment: @Spectre What does a limit mean to you, graphically? And what does the factorial like to you, graphically?

Comment: Well, to me limit is a particular value that a function tends to approach as it's input changes (for instance $\lim_{x \to 0}x^2 = 0$, since as $x$ approaches $0$, the value of $x^2$ tends to $0$. The value gets smaller and closer to $0$ and in fact, at $x = 0$, we have $x^2 = 0$)...

Comment: Also, a factorial ($n!$) is defined as $\prod_{i=1}^{n}i$.

Comment: @Spectre I didn't ask about the definition of factorial, I asked about the graph. What does it look like, to you?

Comment: The graph is what I find a bit doubtful... I didn't try plotting it, but it should look like a path connecting points with integer coordinates $(x,\prod_{i=1}^{x}i)$.

Comment: is it because of the sharp turns that the graph has the limit of such a factorial function is undefined ?

Comment: I mean, not sharp but angular turning points ? Smooth curves have easily determinable derivatives because of the absence of angular turning points, right ?

Comment: @Spectre If it looks like a path connecting those points, then that path has a height at non-integer values. That means you have a definition for the factorial for non-integer input (and you can indeed use that to calculate limits and do calculus with nothing big to stop you). If the factorial is defined only for integers (which it is, both in my opinion and according to your own definition), then the graph consists of just those integer-coordinate points and _nothing in-between_. There just isn't anything to use to "approach" and calculate limits.

Comment: if I connect each point with the other using a straight line, we have a path, right ? We can't all of a sudden say "There's nothing in between", right?

Comment: @Spectre If we connect each point with straight lines (or any other way of connecting them), then we have decided on a definition for the factorial of non-integers. And in that case, we can do limits and calculus (although the derivative at the integer points will be undefined, much like the function $x\mapsto |x|$ has undefined derivative at $0$). But if the factorial is to be defined only for integers, then there is no connection between the points. The graph consists of those points and nothing else.

Comment: so basically, a derivative may exist only if the function is defined on all real numbers and not a fraction of it, unless the function maps to any real number and also makes a smooth turns without sharp turns, is it so ?

Comment: @Spectre For the derivative of a function $f$ to exist a some point (say $a$), the function must first and foremost be defined for input values _close_ to $a$. So something like $f(a+0.000003)$ or $f(a - 0.000008)$ really ought to make sense before you can start differentiating. This doesn't work for the factorial, though; as $3.0000003!$ doesn't make any sense, we can't talk about a "derivative at $3$" for the factorial function..

Comment: Oh... I see... but is my understanding somewhat correct ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the factorial function, $x!$, then it is obvious that the function is discrete, because as you said;

> I doubt that the reason is that factorials are defined only for whole numbers.

This goes way back to the idea of a derivative, it finds the rate of change of a function. We saw that the factorials are just disconnected points (on a graph). However, if you are curious, then you can read ahead.

There is actually something called an "analytic continuation" of the factorials. I won't go into much depth of what an analytic continuation really means, but it's simple idea is to extend the given domain of a function to a larger domain, and it is seen in complex analysis. However, to understand the *the gamma function*, to some extent, you needn't know knowledge of complex analysis. The gamma function, denoted by $\Gamma(x)$ is a function that extends the factorial function to all complex numbers. While inputting real numbers in the gamma function, they cause little problem (except the negative integers), but for complex numbers, we need $\Re(x)>0$, that is, the real part of $x$ needs to be greater than 0. Since you already know that $(x+1)!=(x+1)x!$, it is easy to notice that,
$$(x+n)!=x!\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)$$
If you are not familiar with the $\Pi$, it just acts as $\Sigma$ but for products.
We face a little obstacle here, our aim is to extend the factorials to the reals, but the factorials grow extremely fast. To slower this growth, let us consider a function $\ln(x!)$. From the above identity for $(x+n)!$, we can say that,
$$\ln((x+n)!)=\ln\left(x!\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)\right)$$
and since logarithms change products into sums, it will also change $\Pi$ into $\Sigma$. Here is a little example of this for you to understand it,
$$\ln\left(x_1\cdots x_n\right)=\ln\left(x_1\right)+\cdots+\ln\left(x_n\right)$$
$$\implies\ln\left(\prod_{i=1}^nx_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^n\ln\left(x_i\right)$$
Now, going back to the original formula for $\ln((x+n)!)$, we get,
$$\ln((x+n)!)=\ln(x!)+\ln\left(\prod_{k=1}^n(x+k)\right)$$
$$\ln((x+n)!)=\ln(x!)+\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(x+k)$$
Keep this formula in mind, it'll come in handy later.

Now, seemingly unrelated, consider the limit,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln(N+x)-\ln(N)$$
It is easily evaluated to,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln\left(\frac{N+x}{N}\right)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac{x}{N}\right)=\ln(1+0)=0$$
Now, going back to the formula we had for $\ln((x+n)!)$,
$$\ln((N+n)!)\approx \ln(N!)+\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(N)$$
$$\ln((N+n)!)\approx\ln(N!)+n\ln(N)$$
$$\ln(n!)+\sum_{k=1}^{N}\ln(n+k)\approx\sum_{k=1}^N\ln(k)+n\ln(N)$$
$$\ln(n!)\approx\sum_{k=1}^N\ln(k)-\sum_{k=1}^N\ln(n+k)+n\ln(N)$$
It is easy to prove that if $N\to\infty$, then the approximation becomes a true equality,
$$\ln(n!)=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^N\left(\ln(k)-\ln(n+k)\right)+n\ln(N)$$
Exponentiating both sides,
$$n!=\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left[{\sum\limits_{k=1}^N\ln\left(\frac{k}{n+k}\right)+n\ln(N)}\right]$$
Since logarithms converted products into sums, exponentiation converts sums into products, as shown below, with a little example;
$$e^{x_1+\cdots+x_n}=e^{x_1}\cdots e^{x_n}$$
$$e^{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nx_i}=\prod_{i=1}^n e^{x_i}$$
Going back to the original formula, here is the key assumption, **we must assume that it holds for all real** $x$ **rather than just integers here**. It is not a problem, as this formula can already input real numbers without a problem in computation.
$$x!=\lim_{N\to\infty}\exp\left[{\sum\limits_{k=1}^N\ln\left(\frac{k}{x+k}\right)+x\ln(N)}\right]$$
We brang down the limit using a simple property of limits here,
The expression now becomes,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}e^{x\ln(N)}\prod_{k=1}^Ne^{\ln\left(\frac{k}{x+k}\right)}$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}e^{\ln(N^x)}\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{k}{x+k}$$
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}N^x\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{k}{x+k}$$
This formula is sufficient to generalize the factorials, as you can input any $x$ and find the value of $x!$ using this. This formula was first given by Leonhard Euler, which he later showed to be equal to the integral,
$$\int_0^1(-\ln(t))^x\mathrm{d}t$$
There is no easy way to show these two expressions as equal, as far as I know, but this is defined as the $\Gamma(x+1)$, which gives $x!$, $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$
$$\Gamma(1+x)=\int_0^1(-\ln(t))^x\mathrm{d}t$$
With a simple $u$-substitution, we get the following expression:
$$\Gamma(1+x)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t}t^x\mathrm{d}t$$
This is because the gamma function, $\Gamma(x)$ is defined as $(x-1)!$.
This expression now works for any $x$, thus taking its derivative, and taking its integral is possible, as it is continuous, unlike the discrete factorial function. I'll leave it as an exercise to you, but if you need help with that, you can ask in the comment section of this answer!

**#1:** Once you find the derivative of $\Gamma(1+x)$, that is, an expression for $\Gamma'(1+x)$ (in integral form, probably), it'd also be nice for you to study some properties of $\psi(x)$, the logarithmic derivative of $\Gamma(x)$, and some properties of the Euler-Mascharoni constant, $\gamma$. The $\psi(x)$ function introduces a relation between the $\Gamma(x)$ and $H_x$ (the harmonic numbers) functions. And also helps to relate $\Gamma$ with $\zeta$, the Riemann zeta function. A little start for you;
$$\psi(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\ln\Gamma(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$$
from which you can obtain,
$$\psi(1+x)=\frac{1}{x}=\psi(x)$$
and with the relation that $\psi(1)=-\gamma$, it is easy to obtain a relation between the harmonics and the factorials.

**#2**: I'd suggest you integrate $\Gamma(x)$ on a domain $[a,b]$, leave your answer in the form of an integral with the bounds $0$ and $\infty$, as from what I got after integrating it, the integrand is quite large and finding a closed form for that is useless because when you plug in the values of $a$ and $b$ it becomes much easier than before to calculate the integral.

**#3**: After reading this post myself, I feel like I might've not made the fact that $\Gamma(x)=(x-1)!$ clear enough, so remember that.

Comment: You need some restrictions on the formulae you derived. For instance for the limit expression you need to assume $x\ne -1,-2,-3,\ldots$. For the integrals, you need to assume $x>-1$.

Comment: @Gary Well yes, although I did not explicitly mention it for the integrals, I did mention that negative integers do cause problems in the formula I am going to derive. Thanks for the correction though, much appreciated :D.