# Proving $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$

Tags: real-analysis, factorial, gamma-function

> Given $g(x)=\frac{x}{x!(-x)!}$ equals $0$ for all integer values of $x$ and the functions $\sin(\pi x)$ and $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2x})$ having the same set of roots. Also knowing $(\frac{1}{2})!=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}$, derive a striking relationship from the previous conditions between the factorial function a trigonometric function.

I read a proof for this which derived
$$\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}$$
but the proof was rather unsatisfying and failed to use the aforementioned conditions. My derivations has remained unsuccessful, can someone please provide a clever proof? Also, list the thought process of your approach to the question!

thanks in advance

Comment: Once you know that $\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)\sin(\pi x)$ is entire, you only need to show it is bounded

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/714482/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805652/321264 among several others.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $\Gamma(p) \cdot \Gamma(1-p)=\frac{\pi}{\sin (p\pi)}$ for $p \in (0,\: 1)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/714482/prove-that-gammap-cdot-gamma1-p-frac-pi-sin-p-pi-for-p-in-0)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the original definition Euler came up with for $\Gamma(x)$ before the integral form was actually this,
$$\lim_{N\to\infty}N^{x-1}\prod_{k=1}^N\frac{k}{k+x-1}$$
which I previously derived in this post: [Derivatives or Integrals of Factorials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3890964/derivatives-or-integrals-of-factorials/4833818?noredirect=1#comment10291459_4833818)

You can just plug in this definition in $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)}$$
and after some simplification you get the following product,
$$x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$$
Euler also showed that,
$$\sin x=x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{\pi^2k^2}\right)$$
Plugging in $\pi x$ for $x$ in the above formula (called the "sine product formula" which you can easily find a proof of, on google) gives us,
$$\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi}=x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{\pi^2x^2}{\pi^2k^2}\right)$$
$$\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi}=x\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)$$
Which happens to be exactly the product we got after simplifying $$\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)}$$
This implies that,
$$\frac{\sin\pi x}{\pi}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)}$$
$$\frac{\pi}{\sin\pi x}=\Gamma(x)\Gamma(1-x)$$